# Extracting a string from another page JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display and extract a string from another page. The page in question will be a ftp:// HTML page. I've tried a few different methods and have been reading several similar posts that don't answer my question.

The page I'm requesting will only have one line, which is the line I need.
For example when `Home.html` is the main page. Then when `returned.html` is the page I am requesting, and it simply contains `true` or `false`.

**My code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var HTML = function ( address, callback ) 
{
    if ( !window.XMLHttpRequest ) return;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
    if ( callback && typeof( callback ) === 'function' ) {
        callback( this.responseXML );
    }
}

xhr.open( 'GET', address );
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();
};

    function GetResponse()
    {
        getHTML ('ftp://192.168.2.5/1.html', function (response) { 
            var docele = document.querySelector('divNext');
            docele.innerHTML = response.documentElement.innerHTML;
        });
    }
</script>

<style>
div.hidden {
    display:none;
}
div.visible {
    display:visible;
}
</style>
```

In this I'm trying to load the page into a div, but I'm also needing that into a variable to define other things later on.

Comment: impossible. this is just impossible to achieve due to security limitations of browsers.

Comment: The browser I'm using is a slim version of IE (5, supposedly). It's on a device and security isn't an issue just communication.

Comment: "security isn't an issue" — You might not care about security, but the software you use does.

Comment: ie 5.. sorry but you'll not get any support here. nobody of us cares about dead, obsolete software. all of us are happy microsoft even removed support for IE10 and below. what you could do is something like wrapping this ftp in a local nginx instance and tunnel it through as http. alternatively you could just write a little proxy in c++ or visual basic or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since switching to `ftp` involves a change of protcol, you will hit the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Since you aren't requesting the document over HTTP, you can't add the HTTP headers needed to grant you permission to access the document via [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

So there is no way to directly access the FTP server from JavaScript in the page.

You need to make the data available over HTTP. You could do this by writing server side code to proxy it on the server hosting the HTML document you are embedding the JavaScript in.

If you want to write the code in JavaScript, you can use Node.js to run it on your server.